# What are the keybindings for drop pod control?

Tags: planetside-2

I used to have full control over my drop pods when they dropped (sometimes more, sometimes less). However, I went on a spree and rebound a number of keys relating to flight control, and now find I have lost more than half of that control - specifically, I have full lateral movement control (left/right keys), but no vertical movement control (up/down buttons). I have tried WASD (no effect), and have tried my Xbox controller (which I bound many of my flight controls to - again, no effect). The net effect is that landing on anything smaller than a bio lab is virtually impossible, and landing somewhere useful on said bio lab is a matter of luck.

I believe my rebinding of keys is what caused my problems. What keybindings influence drop pod flight controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it (rebound varies keys), it seems it's bound to your Aircraft Throttle Up and Throttle Down for vertical movement. Yaw left and right are horizontal movement.

One way to make this work is set your Throttle Up/Down Yaw Left/Right to have 2 controls each, one the default WASD and the second for your controller.

Comment: Thanks! I never would have thought to look at the throttle...